# Android: Proper interpretation of sensor values

Tags: android, rotational-matrices, sensormanager

So I've been poring over the [SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) documentation trying to get a handle on how to figure out what direction is north, relative to a given axis of the phone. I've drawn a little image that illustrates my conception of how the coordinate system works:

[image: my conception of the coordinate system]

So if the world coordinates are **x**, **y** and **z**, where Magnetic north is along **z** and **y** points towards the sky, and the coordinates of the phone are **Px**, **Py** and **Pz**, then I'd like to be able to calculate the projection of each vector onto the other.

It seems like SENSOR_TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR might be the right thing to be looking at, but it seems like that's not giving me enough information to get all these projections. Am I supposed to normalize ROTATION_VECTOR and add it to the axis I care about, then pull out the components?

The other big single sensor seems to be SENSOR_TYPE_ORIENTATION, but again I'm not clear on what to do with these values. If I want to know the three projections of the real-world coordinate system onto **Py**, would I just rotate [0, 1, 0] along the given coordinates, like so:

```
// Assume here that I've received values
// and broken them out into 
// a = azimuth
// p = pitch
// r = roll

// Convert to radians
a = a*Math.Pi/180;
p = p*Math.PI/180;
r = r*Math.PI/180;

// Given that Py is initially 0, 1, 0, apply general rotation matrix:
float[] Py = new float[3];
Py[0] = -Math.cos(p)*Math.sin(a) + Math.sin(p)*Math.sin(r)*Math.cos(a);
Py[1] = Math.cos(p)*Math.cos(a) + Math.sin(p)*Math.sin(r)*Math.sin(a);
Py[2] = Math.sin(p)*Math.cos(a);
```

Where I just got those formulas from the formula for [general rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations) (since it's rotating a unit vector, you can just select the center column). I would think that the components of the variable Py would then be the projections of **x**, **y** and **z** onto **Py**, but do I have that backwards? Is it instead the projections of **Py** onto each of the three real-world axes?

Finally, I've noticed that there's a getRotationMatrixFromVector() option, which seems like it calculates these projections for you, but again I'm not sure if I have things completely backwards. If I want to know the three projections of **x**. **y** and **z** onto **Py**, do I get the 2nd column of the Rotation Matrix, or the 2nd row?

(Sorry for the very wordy version of what's probably a quite simple question, I figure it's better for future confused people to be very explicit about the coordinate system, which is my major point of confusion).

Comment: I can't remember exactly how that all worked but that sourcecode [here (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/hardware/SensorManager.java#1188) helped me once.